# Assign the queried data to variable in div

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am sorry for my English.
My problem is this:
In 
The queried data is displayed on the div named "bilgi", but I cannot post the div data shown.
I know div data cannot be posted, but I don't know what to do.
Can you edit the code and help?
The query named "bilgi" must be postable.

```
 <form method="post" name="payment-form" class="payment-form rake-payment-form" id="payment-form" action="userload" >

     <div class="form-group">
    <label>Kart üzerindeki ad ve soyad</label>
    <input type="text" name="holder" id="holder" class="form-control" placeholder="Adı Soyadı"  autocomplete="off" onfocus="this.select()"/>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label>Kart numaranız</label>
    <input type="text" name="showNumber" id="showNumber" class="form-control" maxlength="19" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Kredi Kartı Numarası" />
</div>
<div id="bilgi"></div>

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning" onclick="rake.payment();" id="panel-do-payment-btn">ÖDEME YAP /></button>

</form>

 <script>
        $("#showNumber").keyup(function (e) {
            var binStr = $("#showNumber").val();
             if(binStr.length===6)
           {
             $.getJSON("https://lookup.binlist.net/"+binStr, function (data) {
            $("#bilgi").html(
              "<table>" +
                "<tr><td>Banka Adı : </td><td>" +
                data["bank"]["name"] +
                "</td></td>" +
                "<tr><td>Şehir : </td><td>" +
                data["bank"]["city"] +
                "</td></tr>" +
                "<tr><td>Shema : </td><td>" +
                data["scheme"] +
                "</td></tr>" +
                "<tr><td>Type : </td><td>" +
                data["type"] +
                "</td></tr>" +
                "<tr><td>Ülke : </td><td>" +
                data["country"]["name"] +
                "</td></tr>" +
                "<tr><td>Para Birimi : </td><td>" +
                data["country"]["currency"] +
                "</td></tr>
    </table>"
            );
          });
           }
        });
      </script>
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'cannot post the div data'? Are you just trying to display the response? Or are you trying to send a POST request to a server using the div?

Comment: I'm using google translate.
I want to explain more clearly.
The data queried in <script> are displayed in the div named "bilgi".
I'm trying to post the displayed div content.
It's in div <form> </form> with the name bilgi and there are different form data, but I can't send the div content with just bilgi.. "<tr> <td> Bank Name: </td> <td>" +

I need to submit this section with other form data.

Comment: https://codepen.io/osmanceliktr/pen/eYJmZrm

I am trying to send the "Bank name" section that returns after the query used here to a different page.

Comment: Add a `type="hidden"` input field that will hold the bank name so when you submit the form it'll be included.

Comment: I'm struggling now and that's all my knowledge.
Can you edit the code and write it. Can you help me?

Comment: I rearranged it for better understanding. Would you check?

Comment: What page are you trying to send it to?

Comment: the other page for the same server.
page name: userload.php

Comment: I have to assign the queried data to a variable.
I need to keep the assigned data in the variable.
how do i do this
I think this is the solution.

Comment: Across pages you need to use forms or use URL parameters.

Comment: @philip-rollins , You don't understand what I mean.
Anyway, I hope someone different understands.
Thanks

Comment: HI, so when user click on any `tr` you need to assign that value i.e : bankname inside `showNumber` or any hidden input inside form ?

Comment: I explain the subject very clearly, but you don't want to understand it.
<div id = "bilgi"> </div>

I show the answer returned with json in id = "bilgi" and I need to post this displayed data to the other page.

Comment: I think I asked a very difficult question.